# How to use local Github ssh key when issuing remote git commands on another machine via ssh

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, ssh

I have a local machine with an ssh keypair with the public one on github. As we all know, this allows me to interface with Github without the need to enter a username/password each time.

I also have a remote machine, which I can ssh into using the same public key. Visual Studio Code, allows me to interface with this machine via a workspace. And I noticed that when I run git commands via its terminal interface, I don't get a password prompt.

When I try to run the same git commands via an ssh session I started via my terminal, I'm prompted for a password.

How is Visual Studio Code achieving this? How can I achieve this with an ssh session started via my regular terminal? **Note that I do not want to put my key pair on this remote machine**.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

---

**EDIT**

I just want to note that this question might become more interesting when [github removes the option of password authentication](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/) later next year.

Comment: Which OS is your host machine (running VS Code)?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Okay. It's most likely agent forwarding. I'll write an answer.

Comment: I wonder why you just don't add the remote machine's public key to your GitHub account ?

Comment: @NicolasVoron (at a high level - the answer is because I'm newish to this and it didn't feel as obvious to me) I discarded this early on because it was a new client and didn't want anyone being able to access the repo straight away... But now that you remind me, it makes a lot of sense to do that... and add my own user to the machines as an extra layer of protection.

Comment: @NicolasVoron Oh so many reasons.  Who owns the remote machine?  If it's not also you then you have all kinds of security concerns about giving someone else's machine direct access to your github account.  While agent forwarding can also open the same backdoor, it's only open while you are logged in and so a smaller surface of attack.

Comment: @NicolasVoron Also read here the heading [SSH Key Sprawl Poses Security & Operational Risk](https://www.beyondtrust.com/blog/entry/ssh-key-management-overview-6-best-practices)

Comment: @PhilipCouling thanks for that. I'm a bit of a leaf blowing around in the wind right now!

Comment: @PhilipCouling You are right. I interpreted "i have a remote machine" as "i own an other machine". But if he is not the owner of this second machine, then agent forwarding is the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical way to do this on the terminal is using [agent forwarding](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/overview/using-ssh-agent-forwarding).

The principle is that you have an "Agent" running on your local machine that has access to your private keys.  Typically the agent will have your private keys loaded and decrypted in memory.  When you ssh into a remote machine you specify "Agent Forwarding" to give the remote machine access to your local agent via your SSH connection.

This lets your user (and 'root') on the remote machine request your local Agent to sign ssh connection requests.

---

Assuming a *nix host or Mac then you are most likely using OpenSSH for your client.  To setup your agent, and add your private key to it:

```
ssh-add
```

Or if you have a special name for your private key then type:

```
ssh-add path/to/private/key
```

Then when you ssh into your remote machine just add the `-A` switch to forward the agent:

```
ssh -A remote-machine
```

This will let your user session (and root) use your local SSH key instead of anything stored on the remote host.  Git will implicitly pick use the agent, you don't need to give it any special instruction.

---

If you are using Windows and Putty then it's worth mentioning [pageant](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html) which works with Putty.  This is the Windows equivalent of using ssh-add.  It has its own GUI which is fairly self explanatory.

Comment: Awesome it works! One thing that tripped me up was I forgot to change from http to the ssh url in `.git/config`. Bounty to be rewarded in 23 hrs